# Does system("CLS") also clear my variable storage in c++

Tags: c++

I was working on a project to make **ball/object hit game** in c++. 
I used `system("cls");` to clear the screen and display `Game Over` message. User scores are being reset to zero `0`. while removing `system("cls");` doesn't effect the score of user. Is there any good way to clear the screen without clearing the values of vairables?

Here is an example code. This is the function for level 2 of my game.
I have commented on the line which is causing me this problem.

```
    int level_2(string user_name,int scores)
{
    system("CLS");
    for(int i=5;i>0;i--)
    {
        cout<< "\n\n\n\n\n_________________________________\n";
        cout<< "|                               |\n";
        cout<< "| level 2 starts in "<<i<<" seconds\t|\n";
        cout<< "|                               |\n";
        cout<< "_________________________________\n";
        Sleep(1000);
        system("CLS");
    }   
    system("CLS");
string s = "=======";
string h = "       ";
int i=5, x=10, y=29;
cout << "Press Arrow Keys to move, press q to quit\tWelcome "<<user_name<<"!\n";
cout<< "_________________________________\n";
for(int i=0;i<31;i++)
cout<< "|                               |\n";
cout<< "_________________________________\n";
int x1 = rand() % 19 + 1, 
y1 = rand() % 19+ 1, 
x2 = rand() % 19 + 1, 
y2 = rand() % 19 + 1,
x3=2,
y3=2, 
incX=-1, 
incY=-1,
incXX=1, 
incYY=1,
speed=70;
while (true){

    gotoxy(x, y);
    cout << s;
    if (kbhit())
    {
        gotoxy(x, y);
        cout << h;
        i = getch();
        if (i == 'q')
        {
            break;
        }
        if (i == UP && y>UPLIMIT)
            y=y-2;
        else if (i == DOWN && y<LOWLIMIT)
            y=y+2;
        if (i == LEFT && x>LEFTLIMIT)
            x = x - 3;
        else if (i == RIGHT && x<RIGHTLIMIT-6)
            x = x + 3;
    }
    drawObject(x3, y3);
    print_scores(scores);
    hideObject(x3, y3);
    if(y1<LOWLIMIT)
    drawObject(x1, y1);
    if(y2<LOWLIMIT)
    drawObject(x2, y2);
    Sleep(speed);// to slow down the process
    hideObject(x1, y1);
    hideObject(x2, y2);
    if (x1 == RIGHTLIMIT)   incX = -1;
    if (x1 == LEFTLIMIT)    incX = 1;
    if (y1 == LOWLIMIT) 
    {
        incY = 0;
        speed=40;
    }
    if (x1>x-2 && x1<x+7 ) 
    {   if(y1==y-1)
        {
            incY=-1;
            scores=scores+10;
            total_scores=total_scores+10;
        }
    }
    if (y1 == UPLIMIT)  incY = 1;
    x1 += incX;
    y1 += incY;

    if (x2 == RIGHTLIMIT)   incXX = -1;
    if (x2 == LEFTLIMIT)    incXX = 1;
    if (y2 == LOWLIMIT )
    {
        incYY = 0;
        speed=40;
    }
    if (x2>x-2 && x2<x+7 ) 
    {   if(y2==y-1){
        incYY=-1;
        scores=scores+10;
        total_scores=total_scores+10;
        }
    }
    if (y2 == UPLIMIT)  incYY = 1;
    x2 += incXX;
    y2 += incYY;

    speed=speed-1;
    if (speed<25)
    speed=25;
if(incY==0 && incYY==0)
{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"\n\n\n\tG";Sleep(50);cout<<"a";Sleep(50);cout<<"m";Sleep(50);cout<<"e";Sleep(50);cout<<" ";Sleep(50);cout<<"O";Sleep(50);cout<<"v";Sleep(50);cout<<"e";Sleep(50);cout<<"r";
    system("pause>nul");
    system("cls");     //this line is clearing my scores
    break;
}
if(incY==0 && incYY==0)
break;
if(scores>=score2)
{
    ofstream out("records.txt");
    out<<scores;
    out.close();
    ofstream out1("total_scores.txt");
    out1<<total_scores;
    out1.close();
    break;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhm, that's all `system("cls")` does, clear the screen. It doesn't do *anything* to your variables.

Comment: Where does the `total_scores` variable come from? Is it a global variable?

Comment: Are you sure `system("cls");` is the cause of your problem?

Comment: `system("cls")` has no control over your memory at all.

Comment: There is no way `system("cls")`  **modifies** anything within the memory address of your program. This is not the cause of your problems.

Answer (score -2):

`system("cls")` don't clear the value of variables. If you have problems with it, save the variables in a file before you clear the screen and load after the `system("cls")` line.